# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Boolean, got String with value "0"

Tags: vue.js

I used this package in my Laravel project

```
    Vue.js toggle/switch button.
```

In User Component, I used this toggle/switch button for status in user table

```
  <tr v-for="user in users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td><toggle-button :value="user.status"
        :labels="{checked: 'On', unchecked: 'Off'}"/>
    </td>
  <tr>
```

but throw error Expected Boolean, got String with value.i used v-model="user.status" but didn't work.What is wrong in here ?

Comment: what's the value of `user.status`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim 1 or 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

```
<toggle-button :value="!!parseInt(user.status)"
               :labels="{checked: 'On', unchecked: 'Off'}"/>
```

Your `user.status` value is string. When the value is `'0'` it will return `false`, if the value is something else (`'1', '2'`) will return `true`.